# C# Array 2 threads read same item at same time

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading, thread-safety

If I have the following 2 for loops that will be run on different threads:

```
for (int ii = 1; ii < times.Length; ii+=2)
{
     if (times[ii] - times[ii - 1] > maxGap)
     return false;
}

for (int ii = 2; ii < times.Length; ii += 2)
{
      if (times[ii] - times[ii - 1] > maxGap)
      return false;
}
```

The situation could occur where both threads try to read from an item in `times` Array eg both threads could try and read `times[1]` at the same time.

Given that both threads will only ever read from these arrays, is this a problem eg could it cause my code to crash or any other unexpected negative consequences?

Comment: No. If it is read-only, then there is no problem (of course given no other thread will write, etc.). One two writes or read-write combos will cause troubles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If only read operation is performed then there won't be a problem.
Read and write operation together can cause a problem.

Comment: It is the shared writes which cause problems. Multiple readers are always safe. Multiple writers if they are writing to non-overlapping ranges are also safe.